# VS/Selenium - Object reference not set to an instance of an object with null driver

Tags: c#, selenium, unit-testing, object-reference

I'm trying to get a list of iFrames on a page, but for some reason, I keep getting two errors. Namely, I get null driver and "Object reference not set to an instance of an object" when I do `var iFrame = driver.FindElements(By.TagName("frame"));`. I've spent half a day trying to figure it out and I feel like I'll be stuck in a rut unless I asked for help on Stack Overflow.

BaseiFrame Class:

```
public class BaseIFrame
    {

        protected IWebDriver _driver;
        private ReadOnlyCollection<IWebElement> _elements;
        private ReadOnlyCollection<IWebElement> _iframes;

        public BaseIFrame(IWebDriver _driver)
        {
            this._driver = _driver;
            _iframes = _driver.FindElements(By.TagName("frame"));
            _elements = new ReadOnlyCollection<IWebElement>(_iframes);
        }

        public void GetAlliFrames()
        {
            try
            {
                if (_elements.Count > 0)
                {
                    _driver.SwitchTo().Frame(0);
                }
            }
            catch (Exception e)
            {
                Debug.WriteLine(e.FormatExceptionMessage(this));
                throw;
            }
        }
   }
```

BaseiFrameTests class method which calls BaseiFrame class

```
    public class BaseiFrameTests : SharedBase
    {
        protected IWebDriver _driver;
        private BaseConfig config;
        private BaseConfig initialUrl;

        //string url = "http://127.0.0.1:1024/";

        public BaseiFrameTests()
        {
        }

        public override BaseConfig getConfig()
        {
            return new Config
            {
                initialUrl = "http://the-internet.herokuapp.com/nested_frames"
            };
        }

        public override BaseConfig loadConfig()
        {
            return new BaseConfig();
        }

        public override IWebDriver getDriver()
        {
            return instantiateWebDriver("edge");
        }

        [TestMethod]
        public void AssertiFrameLength()
        {
            BaseIFrame bif = new BaseIFrame(_driver);
            bif.GetAlliFrames();
        }
   }
```

Comment: this._driver = _driver;  i suspect the issue is with driver naming. can you try with different driver names

Comment: can you share the code where you instantiate your driver and how you get to this class? - i can see you're passing it in the constructor, but is it potentially coming in null?

Comment: I'll have to see if I can. My webdriver is instantiated from the BaseiFrameTest class through a complex interface built by the company I work for. I managed to successfully initiate the driver on BaseiFrameTest... but I had to go through hoops to do so interestingly enough.

Comment: See what you can do mate :-)  -  `complex interface` always sounds fun. If needs be, do a simper test outside of your application boundaries. Navigate to somewhere like google and enter anything in the search. That will make sure your driver is working and it's nothing to do with your frames or application under test.

Comment: Just got the green light! However, my supervisor said no deeper than that since it delves into our primary automation codebase. Made the edits. Hopefully they help

Comment: I can see this is an incomplete picture... What happens if you run: BaseIFrame bif = new BaseIFrame(getDriver());

Comment: Any chance you can share your setup method?... Null pointer means your driver is null i.e. Not instantiated.  That getDriver suggests to create it for you and return it....... That's the path I'd follow first.

Comment: Oh hey Rich! I solved it. All I needed to do was initialize getDriver() on new BaseiFrame(); and it worked like a charm :)

Comment: Problem Solved. Good job mate. I wasn't far off but glad you nailed it :-)

Answer (score 0):

Update: I was able to fix my issue by initializing `getDriver()` onto `new BaseiFrame();` in the `AssertiFrameLength` method.